# How could i run user as contributors

Tags: managed-metadata, groups, user

how could i run user with Contributors permissions in termstore group?
Without the user are in the group?
Is it possible?

Running for an user that aint member of the group Contributors in term store group:  `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()` is not working,
Is it some code runt with Contributors permission?

## UPDATE

```
  SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
            {
                using (SPSite secureSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
                {
                    TaxonomySession ts = new TaxonomySession(secureSite);
                    TermStore termStore = ts.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
                    Group group = termStore.Groups["MyGroup"];

                    TermSet termSet = group.CreateTermSet("Termset");

                    termSet.CreateTerm("Term", 1033);

                    termStore.CommitAll();

                }
            });
```

The code abow only works if i set current user to Group Manager or Contributor, is it not possible to run abow code without setting Group Manager or Contributor, i want to use current logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Please stop creating several questions for the same topic. To help anyone finding this topic, I'll post my answer here aswell.

The reason your code is not working is that TaxonomySession uses the user from the HttpContext. I found this [link](https://www.1stquad.com/sharepoint-kompetenz-erfahrung-know-how/blog/default/mai-2013/zugriff-mit-elevated-privilegs-auf-termstore) which is in German but the suggested code looks like this:

```
HttpContext oldContext = null;
try
{
   //Save actual context and null
   oldContext = HttpContext.Current;
   HttpContext.Current = null;
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
      using (var elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
      {
         var taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(elevatedSite);
         var termStore = taxonomySession.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;

         //put your logic here

         termStore.CommitAll();
     }
   });
}
finally
{
   HttpContext.Current = oldContext;
}
```